# Call a function every 10 seconds in C - mbed platform

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, mbed

I could use:

```
while(1==1) 
{

    delay(10);

    f();     // <-- function to be called every 10 seconds

    otherfunctions();

}
```

But this will take just over 10 seconds because the other functions take some time to execute. Is there a delay function that takes into account the time taken by the other functions so I can then call `f()` exactly every 10 seconds?

I've heard that this can be done with a clever  function that can be found in a header file, but I cant remember which one. I think it might have been `#include mbed.h` but even if the function is included in this header file I do not know what it is called or how to search for it.

Does anybody know of a function that can do what I am after?

Comment: On which operating system are you? AFAIK the C standard library has no timer functions.

Comment: How is your program implemented? Do you have threads? What does the program run on?

Comment: The program runs on a Keil micro controller (uses an Arm processor). `#include time.h` has a delay function.

Comment: I think you should be able to set up an interrupt using a timer in the MCU.

Comment: I'm using the mbed IDE. The header file `#include mbed.h` adds lots of functions which make programming the micro controller as simple as programming an Arduino. (A very simple hobbyist micro controller)

Comment: @Binary Judy How do I set up an interrupt timer, and how would it work?

Comment: You need to get current time just before calling the function, then call the other functions, then get current time avain, and calculate how long you still need to sleep. (This is just one way, works if that loop is your entire program/main loop.)

Comment: @hyde this sounds like a clever way to do it. Thanks! Do you know of a function that will return the current time?

Comment: The MCU has a system clock that is always running at whatever frequency, there should be a register where you can set up a timer so that every 10 sec it will interrupt the system and call your function. Of course it takes some setting up but that would be the correct solution considering you are using a microcontroller. Look at the data sheet.

Comment: *Is there a delay function that takes into account the time taken by the other functions*, no but you can compute that time and then `delay(10 - thatTime);` althought of `thatTime > 10` there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @Blue7 You need better than 1 second accuracy I presume. Then it depends on the operating system.

Comment: @Blue7 I can try and help you if you can tell me the microcontroller part number so I can look at it's documentation.

Comment: @BinaryJudy That would be amazing, thank you! The part number is FRDM-KL25Z. I'm super stressed at the moment so this is very helpful.

Comment: Earlier I said it runs on a Keil micro controller. This was wrong sorry. It is a Freescale FRDM-KL25Z. It uses an Arm Cortex M0+ processor.

Comment: @Blue7 Okay, I'll take a look but it may take some time. I'm at work ;)

Comment: @Blue7 I see that it has a PIT (periodic interrupt timer), that's probably what you want to use. Lots of times these dev boards come with example projects, and they almost always include one that uses timers/interrupts. Does this one have anything like that that might help you?

Comment: I have the manual so ill have a look for a PIT tomorrow. TBH this is only for a tiny tiny part of a much bigger project with not much focus on the microcontroller or the code. I was just gonna add in a few lines to show how something could possibly be implemented. If it's to much work though I'm just gonna do it in pseudo code. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately these things usually take some time to figure out. Good luck!

Comment: The fact that you are using mbed is kind of critical to any sort of directly usable answer, you need to have mentioned that in your question, not just in a comment - I have added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should of course start by reading the [mbed handbook](http://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Homepage).  It is not a large API and you can get a good overview of it very quickly.

The mbed platform is a C++ API, so you will need to use C++ compilation.

There are several ways to achieve what you need, some examples:

**Using the `Ticker` class:**

```
#include "mbed.h"

Ticker TenSecondStuff ;

void TenSecondFunction() 
{
    f();
    otherfunctions();
}

int main() 
{
    TenSecondStuff.attach( TenSecondFunction, 10.0f ) ;

    // spin in a main loop.
    for(;;) 
    {
        continuousStuff() ;
    }
}
```

---

**Using `wait_us()` and the `Timer` class:**

```
#include "mbed.h"

int main()
{
    Timer t ;
    for(;;) 
    {
        t.start() ;
        f() ;
        otherfunctions() ;
        t.stop() ;

        wait_us( 10.0f - t.read_us() ) ;
    }
}
```

---

**Using the `Ticker` class, an alternative method:**

```
#include "mbed.h"

Ticker ticksec ;
volatile static unsigned seconds_tick = 0 ;
void tick_sec() 
{
    seconds_tick++ ;
}

int main() 
{
    ticksec.attach( tick_sec, 1.0f ) ;

    unsigned next_ten_sec = seconds_tick + 10 ;
    for(;;) 
    {
        if( (seconds_tick - next_ten_sec) >= 0 )
        {
            next_ten_sec += 10 ;
            f() ;
            otherfunctions() ;
        }

        continuousStuff() ;
    }
}
```

---

**Using mbed RTOS timer**

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "rtos.h"

void TenSecondFunction( void const* )
{
    f();
    otherfunctions();
}

int main() 
{
    RtosTimer every_ten_seconds( TenSecondFunction, osTimerPeriodic, 0);

    for(;;)
    {
        continuousStuff() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it simple try this

```
int delayTime = DELAY_10_SECS;

while(1==1) 
{
    delay(delayTime);

    lastTime = getCurrTicks();  //Or start some timer with interrupt which tracks time

    f();     // <-- function to be called every 10 seconds
    otherfunctions();

    delayTime = DELAY_10_SECS - ( getCurrTicks() - lastTime );  //Or stop timer and get the time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming you have some type of timer counter, perhaps one generated by a timer driven interrupt, try something like this:

```
volatile int *pticker;      /* pointer to ticker */
    tickpersecond = ... ;   /* number of ticks per second */
    /* ... */
    tickcount = *pticker;   /* get original reading of timer */
    while(1){
        tickcount += 10 * tickspersecond;
        delaycount = tickcount-*pticker;
        delay(delaycount);  /* delay delaycount ticks */
        /* ... */
    }
```

This assumes that the ticker increments (instead of decrements), that the codde never get 10 seconds behind on a delay and assumes the number of ticks per second is an exact integer. Since an original reading is used as a basis, the loop will not "drift" over a long period of time.